# Fabric.js image on click and animate outside add function

Tags: image, animation, onclick, fabricjs

Hi I am developing an application with Fabric.js where the user would enter some string and upon clicking on the delete image last word will be deleted and the image would shift to the left.

I am using image like

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(srcImg, function (oImg) {
    canvas.add(oImg);
    oImg.set('left',0);
    oImg.set('top', 100);
    oImg.scale(.55);
    canvas.renderAll();

    // and then, we can animate the image    
    oImg.animate('left', 100, {
        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
    });
    
    oImg.on('mouse:down', function() {
        //some function here
    });
 });
```

Now I want to use the click and the animate outside of the add function, but I get an error `undefined index oImg`. I want to use click and animate elsewhere so that I can remove the last word and use animate to shift the image to the left I am using text for click and the animate right now but I would like to use image.

Comment: Please can you provide a demo of what you tried so far. Please also improve the description of the question to allow us to better understand your issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/geoLjhy0/ this is the fiddle you can see the onclick works inside the function also I have added a global variable and img2 but outside the function this img variable is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fabric.Image.fromURL` is an asynchronous method, so it is normal that it will throw an error of undefined calling it just below it. You have mainly two solutions here:

1. Add the event listener inside the callback:

   ```
   fabric.Image.fromURL('//lorempixel.com/200/200/', function(img) {  
     img2 = img

     ...

     img2.on('mousedown', function () {
       console.log('throws an error');
     });
   });
   ```
2. Call events binding function (always after img2 was created)

   ```
   fabric.Image.fromURL('//lorempixel.com/200/200/', function(img) {  
     img2 = img

     ...

     bindImageEvents(img2)
   });

    function bindImageEvents (imageObject) {
      imageObject.on('mousedown', function () {
        console.log('Something...');
    });
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Not quite was I looking for but that did the trick